# Is it possible to run `bundle viz` excluding production gems?

Tags: ruby, bundler

Is it possible to run the `bundle viz` command excluding gems from a specific group (usually the production one)?

Running `bundle viz --without production` does not work, so the syntax appears somehow different from the one of `bundle install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was recently added, but it hasn't been released yet. See https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/3050

You can try cloning the Bundler git repository and running it from master. The easiest way to do that is to set up a shell alias to run `bundle` from your clone, as described in https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/DEVELOPMENT.md#development-setup